# DataLoader - Download Link missing - Deprecated?

Tags: data-loader

**Background**

Today, I tried to download Dataloader from "Setup > Data Management > Data Loader". It seems like Dataloader is gone.

This raises several questions:

**Question**

- Is Dataloader deprecated?
- Where can I download DataLoader?
- Is there any replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Dataloader deprecated?

No.

> Where can I download DataLoader?

Setup > Data Management > Data Loader. If you can't see this, you [might not have permission](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=installing_the_data_loader.htm&type=5). Make sure you're logged in as a System Administrator.

> Is there any replacement?

There are lots of third party software, as well as the first-party [Open Source Data Loader](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader).

Answer (score 1):

I see it just fine. In both Classic and Lightning

[image]

https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader/releases

You can also go directly to the repository. You can download older versions this way in case you have any issues with zulu.